# Can an existentially quantified type variable be forced to have only a single type?

Tags: scala, existential-type

Consider the following code

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def one: Foo[_ >: T]
  def two: T
  def three(x: T)
}

def test[T](f: Foo[T]) = {
  val b = f.one
  b.three(b.two)
}
```

The method test fails to type check. It says:

```
 found   : (some other)_$1(in value b)
 required: _$1(in value b)
     val x = b.three(b.two)
```

If I am interpreting this correctly, the compiler thinks that b in method test has a type that looks like this (not legal syntax, but hopefully clearer):

```
trait Foo {
   def two: X where ∃ X >: T
   def three(x: X where ∃ X >: T)
}
```

What I was hoping for was that it would have a type like this:

```
∃ X >: T such that trait Foo {
   def two: X
   def three(x: X)
}
```

The intent being that while the precise type X is not known, the compiler knows that its the same unknown type being returned by "two" and expected by "three". This seems different from what happens with normal univerally quantified generics. The following compiles, but exposes the type parameter X which I want to hide as it will vary between instances of Foo:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def one[X >: T]: Foo[X]
  def two: T
  def three(x: T)
}

def test[T, X >: T](f: Foo[T]) = {
  val b = f.one[X]
  b.three(b.two)
}
```

Is there a way to get the same behaviour for existentially quantified generics we get when they're univerally quanified?

Comment: `def test = def wibble` should be just `def wibble` right?

Comment: I think a reason that `∃ X :> T trait Foo` can't be inferred is that _`X`_ is being used in both covariant and contravariant positions.

Comment: ggovan - could you expand on that in a full answer? I can't see why that would matter, but I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Not really, I'm clutching at straws.

Answer (score 2):

`def one: Foo[_ >: T]` is equivalent to

`def one: Foo[U >: T] forSome {type U >: T}`

this one instead works

`def one: Foo[U forSome {type U >: T}]`

I do not however understand why this would make a difference.  It seems like it should not to me. (shrug)

Comment: Interesting. That might be what I'mm looking for. I suspect the difference is that placing the "forSome" inside the square brackets tells the compiler there's only one U. Why that would be, though, I don't know.

Comment: @stew This compiles for me, but then how do you implement this interface? I can't seem to figure out how to write a method that returns an existential type like `Foo.one` above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the compiler thinks that

```
b.two: _>:T
b.three(_>:T)
```

i.e. two is a supertype of T and three requires a supertype of T. But a supertype of T is not necessarily assignment compatible with another supertype of T, as in this example:

```
A >: B >: C
def get:A
def put(B)
put(get) // type mismatch
```

So if all the information we have is that they are supertypes of T then we cannot do this safely.
We have to explicitly tell the compiler that they are the same supertype of T.

```
trait Foo[T] {
  type U <: T
  def one: Foo[U]
  def two: T
  def three(x: T)
}
```

Then just set `U` when you implement the trait:

```
val x = new Foo[Dog]{
  type U = Mammal
  ...
```

I would prefer this approach over the existential types due to the cleaner syntax and the fact that this is core Scala and does not need the feature to be imported.

Comment: That's true, but unfortunately I really do want to hide the exact type of the type parameter in the return value of "one". The exact type is more precise than I want the caller to see, and will be dependent on the value of type Foo being used.

Comment: The exact type is hidden from all callers. Only the instance itself has any knowledge of the type, all others just know that it is a supertype of T.

Comment: Sure, but I'm only asking the fact the return type of "two" and parameter type of "two" are the same to be respected in the methods of the instance. This happens for universally quantified generics.