# What is the significant of the placement of the "forSome" clause in Scala generics syntax?

Tags: scala, existential-type

Based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402431/values-with-existential-type-parameters), it appears that placing "forSome" after a component of the type definition is different from placing it at the end of the whole thing. For instance, it seems there is a difference between the following:

```
def one: Foo[U >: T] forSome {type U >: T}

def one: Foo[U forSome {type U >: T}]
```

The Scala language specification does not seem to say anything about the difference, and I would have imagined that moving the quantifiers to the outside would make no difference. If it did make a difference, I would have thought it would be as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226004/what-is-and-when-to-use-scalas-forsome-keyword), which basically says Set[X forSome {type X}] allows X to vary between set elements, where Set[X] forSome {type X} does not. However, this does not seem to be the whole story and/or is not correct, because this does not compile:

```
trait Bar {
   def test: Set[X] forSome {type X}
}

def test(b: Bar) {
  val set = b.test
  val h = set.head
  set.contains(h)
}
```

But this does:

```
trait Bar {
   def test: Set[X forSome {type X}]
}

def test(b: Bar) {
  val set = b.test
  val h = set.head
  set.contains(h)
}
```

It seems as if Set[X] forSome {type X} creates a separate abstract type for every usage site in the instantiated class, where Set[X forSome {type X}] creates only one and uses it for the entire class. This is the opposite of what I would have expected and seems inconsistent with the answer reference above.

Comment: This should clarify the situation at least a little bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226004/what-is-and-when-to-use-scalas-forsome-keyword

Comment: @Andrey - That's interesting, particular because the accepted answer to the question implies that the semantics are the opposite of what I think I'm seeing.

Comment: @Andrey - actually I would go slightly further and say that the accepted answer to that question isn't useful as an answer to this one and may be flat-out wrong. See my revised example above.

Comment: The second last code block on [this page](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/) explains the difference. I think your first one is saying _All Sets_, and the second one is _A Set for all Whatevers_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of observations to start with: `X forSome { type X }` is just a fancy way of writing `Any`—it's a type we don't know anything about, so it must be at the top of the type hierarchy. If you don't believe me, ask the compiler:

```
scala> implicitly[Any =:= X forSome { type X }]
res0: =:=[Any, _] = <function1>
```

Yep, it agrees.

Relatedly, the following won't compile:

```
scala> val xs: Set[X forSome { type X }] = Set[Int](1, 2, 3)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
 required: Set[X forSome { type X }]
Note: Int <: X forSome { type X }, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
```

Which isn't surprising given what we just learned. `Set` is invariant in its type parameter, so a `Set[Int]` isn't a `Set[X forSome { type X }]` (i.e., a `Set[Any]`).

Given all of this it's also not too surprising that the second `test` method compiles. When we take the head of `b.test`, we get an `X forSome { type X }` (i.e., an `Any`), and we need an `X forSome { type X }` (i.e., an `Any`) for `b.test.contains`.

So now for the first `Bar`. Consider the following:

```
scala> val xs: Set[X] forSome { type X } = Set[Int](1, 2, 3)
xs: Set[_] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

Here we've said `xs` is a set of some specific type `X`, but we're immediately going to forget everything about `X`. Note that unlike the `xs` definition above, this does compile, since we're not saying that `xs` is a set of anything, just that it's a set of some specific type we don't know (or rather that the compiler doesn't know).

This means that there's absolutely no possible `a` that will make `xs.contains(a)` compile. Let's try an obvious one:

```
scala> xs.contains(1)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: X
              xs.contains(1)
                          ^
```

The error message here is interesting—*we* know that `X` is actually `Int`, but the compiler doesn't, since we explicitly asked it to forget that fact with the `forSome { type X }`.  You can see a similarly interesting message by rewriting your `test` method for the first `Bar` as follows:

```
def test(b: Bar) = b.test.contains(b.test.head)
```

This also won't compile, with the following message:

```
found   : (some other)X(in method test) where type (some other)X(in method test)
required: X(in method test) where type X(in method test)
      def test(b: Bar) = b.test.contains(b.test.head)
                                             ^
```

That is, *even though* we just pulled that `b.test.head` out of `b.test`, we still can't apply `b.test.contains` to it. We've told the compiler that the only thing it knows about the item type of `b.test` is that it exists, so it's not going to keep track of the fact that `b.test.head` is the kind of thing that we should be able to apply `b.test.contains` to.