# How to access a class's type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I have a type-parameterized abstract class that contains a val and a method that both use its type parameter

```
abstract class Foo[T](val state: T){
  def foo(arg: T){
    ...
  }
}
```

I also have a class that extends this abstract class and provides the type parameter and a value for `state`

```
class Bar(myNumber: Int) extends Foo[Int](myNumber){
   ...
}
```

I pass an instance of `Bar` to another class that accepts any subclass of `Foo`, and I would like to call the method `foo` on `state`, but I'm running into some trouble:

```
class Baz(val f: Foo[_]){
    f.foo(f.state)
}
```

This gives the error:

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Baz.this.f.state.type (with underlying type _$1)
 required: _$1
         f.foo(f.state)
```

Is there any way to give `Baz` knowledge of `Bar`'s type parameter so that it compiles correctly? Or is that even what I want to do?

**Edit**

To clarify, I have many classes similar to `Bar` that extend `Foo` and provide their own type parameter, state, and implementation of `foo`. I would like users of my library to be able to pass any of them to `Baz` without worrying about the type parameter `T` since its just an implementation detail of each subclass of `Foo`.

So I would strongly prefer not to do this:

```
class Baz[T](val f: Foo[T]){
  f.foo(f.state)
}
```

Comment: [Existentials considered harmful.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-debate/1uJ3cpvBiDs) That thread covers why, and different solutions that could be used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an existentially quantified type variable be forced to have only a single type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402431/can-an-existentially-quantified-type-variable-be-forced-to-have-only-a-single-ty)

Comment: That question is different because the asker specifies a type T and wants the existential type to be a superclass of it. In my question I want to ignore it entirely. Additionally I tried their answer and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a

```
def fooOnState[T](ft: Foo[T]) = ft.foo(ft.state)
```

calling it with a `Foo[_]` is ok.

Still, existentials are best avoided most of the time, but it depends on your real code.

Comment: This would work, but then how would I access the `T` that I need to call `fooOnState`? I have many different subclasses of `Foo` each with their own `T`, etc...

Comment: Not sure I understand, you may call fooOnState passing it a Foo[_], in your code,  just call fooOnState(f) rather than f.foo(f.state) you are not required to know T for that.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know you could omit that type parameter when calling. Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the type parameter with a "type member" in a trait would let you write generic code that works for all state types, at the expense of a little verbosity to specify the type member in each subclass:

```
trait Foo {
  type StateT  // this is the "type member"
  val state: StateT
  def foo(arg: StateT): Unit
}

class Bar(myNumber: Int) extends Foo {
  type StateT = Int     // this is the verbose part
  override val state = myNumber  // this, too
  override def foo(arg: StateT) { /* something specific here */ }
}

class Baz(val f: Foo) {
  f.foo(f.state)  // generic code, works on any Foo subclass
}
```